# Appium clicks not registering on iOS devices in Saucelabs

Tags: ios, appium, saucelabs

Hybrid app on iOS device (while running through automation) logs the user out of the app (considering as inactivity) although user is performing all the activities required.

Using Appium 1.8 and running automated scripts for both iOS and Android, majorly using WebView (on real devices in Saucelabs). The app is designed to log the user out, if they are not active for certain time. This is recent change on timeout in the app. Now android is able to complete all the tests, but for some reason iOS is logging out the user at the designated inactivity timeout, although the user is performing all the clicks and actions. I have used TouchAction and Sequence classes to emulate real user taps instead of usual click() as present in the our scripts, but no luck still.